# How to minimise waiting for main thread for touchmove

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, chromium

My task is to drag around a div in an html page, and do it as fast as possible, because the target platform is mobile (chrome android) But I found it a bit laggy on chrome (android), so I started profiling the app and found that my touch events are waiting for the main thread approx for ~10ms on a huawei p8.

My question is how can I minimise this time, hadn't found any solution, seems like it's not possible.

here is a sample jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/bbvarga/p94btq6e/):

js part:

```
document.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
})

var box = document.getElementById('box');
var x = 0;
var y = 0;
var px = 0;
var py = 0;
var handler = null;


function paint() {
  box.style.setProperty(
    'transform', 
    `translate3d(${px}0px, ${py}px, 0px)`, 
    'important'
  );
  handler = null;
}

box.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) {
  console.log('ts');
  x = e.touches[0].pageX;
  y = e.touches[0].pageY;
});

box.addEventListener('touchend', function() {
  console.log('te');
  if (handler) {
    window.cancelAnimationFrame(handler);
    handler = null;
  }
});

box.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
  console.log('tm');
  px = e.touches[0].pageX;
  py = e.touches[0].pageY;
  if (!handler) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(paint);
  }
});
```

html:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="box">
    </div>  
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: #efefef;
}
#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
#box {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

and here's a screenshot from the timeline, as you can see the red lines under the Touch Move events are quite long ( that's while the browser is waiting for the main thread, it's also under the summary of Touch Move event, you can see at the bottom of the attached screenshoot). The real job, recalc the style, painting, composing is done quite fast compared to the waiting time.

Now the framerate in this minimalistic example is acceptable, but I feel that if I have images, and others stuff in that div, some calculation, these long touch move events slows down my framerate.

If you want to achieve a 60fps, you just have ~17ms for each frame, and if waiting is ~10 you have just 7ms for the real job. :(

[image]

A note: In mobile safari it's fast, and can't feel this delay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ~10ms of waiting is the time from when the input event comes in until the main thread picks it up when it generates the next frame. From **that** time you have ~16ms of frame budget

What you're seeing is input latency. It won't affect the smoothness of your effect (your JS handler is well within the budget) but it adds ~1 frame of latency (so the box doesn't stick exactly to the finger). This happens because the OS passes the input event to the browser process. It's then sent to the renderer process that contains your page. From there, it's queued on the main thread but wont get picked up until the main thread is ready to generate a new frame (and there's a bit of queueing going on at each step). The touch move in the timeline ends once the frame has been pushed to the GPU.

Unfortunately, much of this isn't really under your control but it should be relatively constant as long as your main thread isn't saturated.